# Raw query to display promotion name and how many orders it has been used with?

Tags: sales-order, sql, promotions

Title says it. I am looking for a raw query (direct sql) to tell me a promotions name, and how many orders it has been used on. Results should look something like this

```
+----------------------------+-------------+
| Promotion Name             | # of Orders |
+----------------------------+-------------+
| Full Price                 |           2 |
| Looting Sale               |           3 |
+----------------------------+-------------+
```

I am having a hard time even finding where the promotion name is kept, much less the times of orders

Answer (score 1):

This view works. It displays promotion name, how many orders promo was applied to, percentage of those orders and the average total of those orders.

```
CREATE VIEW promotions  AS
SELECT 'Full Price'     AS 'Promotion Name'
     , COUNT(entity_id) AS '# of Orders' 
     , CONCAT(ROUND(
        (((SELECT COUNT(b.entity_id) FROM sales_flat_order b WHERE b.applied_rule_ids IS NULL) 
        / (SELECT COUNT(entity_id) FROM sales_flat_order a)) * 100), 1), '%') AS '% of Orders'
     , ROUND(AVG(subtotal), 2) AS 'Avg. Total'

FROM sales_flat_order

WHERE applied_rule_ids IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT sr.name AS 'Promotion Name'
     , (SELECT COUNT(entity_id) FROM sales_flat_order WHERE applied_rule_ids = sr.rule_id) '# of Orders'
     , CONCAT(ROUND(
        (((SELECT COUNT(b.entity_id) FROM sales_flat_order b WHERE b.applied_rule_ids = sr.rule_id) 
        / (SELECT COUNT(entity_id) FROM sales_flat_order a)) * 100), 1), '%') AS '% of Orders'
     , ROUND(AVG(sfo.subtotal), 2) AS 'Avg. Total'

FROM salesrule        sr
   , salesrule_coupon src
   , sales_flat_order sfo

WHERE sr.rule_id = src.rule_id AND sr.rule_id = sfo.applied_rule_ids

GROUP BY sr.rule_id;
```

And then just

```
SELECT * FROM promotions;
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Promotion Name             | # of Orders | % of Orders | Avg. Total |
+----------------------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Full Price                 |          25 | 71.4%       |     308.72 |
| $201 CREDIT - AMAZON LOCAL |           7 | 20.0%       |     385.71 |
| Looting Sale               |           3 | 8.6%        |     277.67 |
+----------------------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```